# Xubuntu freezes when turning it off

Tags: freeze, xubuntu

I installed Xubuntu 17.10 to my laptop Asus GL553VW. It started to work well but as I tried to shut it down, the system won't react to anything. The same happens if I choose Log out/Shut Down or type `sudo poweroff` to the console. Is it a bug? How can I shut down Xubuntu correctly?

Comment: What's happening if you log into `tty` using `alt+f2` and then issue `sudo shutdown -h 0`? Is the system halting with a `sudo halt` command?

Comment: Try switching over to text mode with `alt+f2` or `alt+f3` and running `sudo shutdown -h 0`. Is there any limitations on your user that you can think of?